# Avoid NZEC error in Erlang in SPOJ

Tags: erlang

I've written code in Erlang, and I get the correct answer on my machine. But when I submit it on [SPOJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOJ) it gives an NZEC (non zero exit code) error. I have used built-in functions like `halt()` and `init:stop()`, and their specification clearly says that they are used to avoid non-zero exit code error. But still I get the same error. How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT** The code as required by a comment:

```
-module(factorial).
-export([main/0]).

main() ->
    {ok, [No_of_cases]} = io:fread("", "~d"),
    loop(No_of_cases).

loop(0) ->
%init:stop();
halt(1);
loop(No_of_cases) ->
    {ok, [Number]} = io:fread("", "~d"),
    ResultFactorial = find_factorial(Number,1),
    io:format("~p~n",[ResultFactorial]),
    loop(No_of_cases-1).

find_factorial(0,Product) ->
    Product;
find_factorial(Number,Product) ->
    find_factorial(Number-1,Product*Number).
```

Comment: Maybe if you could poost a bit of your code or at least an error report it would be easier to help you...

Comment: -module(factorial).
-export([main/0]).
main() ->
     {ok, [No_of_cases]} = io:fread("", "~d"),
     loop(No_of_cases).

loop(0) ->
     %init:stop();
     halt(1);
loop(No_of_cases) ->
          {ok, [Number]} = io:fread("", "~d"),
          ResultFactorial = find_factorial(Number,1),
          io:format("~p~n",[ResultFactorial]),
          loop(No_of_cases-1).
     
find_factorial(0,Product) ->
     Product;
find_factorial(Number,Product) ->
     find_factorial(Number-1,Product*Number).

This code is for finding factorial.Running well on my machine but in spoj giving non zero exit code error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer. The trick is that your module name always has to be `tested` and the entry point should be function **main** . For example, after compilation it should be run as **tested:main()**.

Comment: Note that as of 2017, the Erlang module name must be `prog`.